# how to stop tomcat7 in ubuntu?

Tags: tomcat7

I have installed apache tomcat7 using the command apt-get.
Now whenever I start my system, tomcat is running. I want to stop the tomcat so that I can start it within eclipse.

I tried stoping it with shutdown.sh command and I am getting the below error :

```
admin@admin-eMachines-E727:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin$ sudo /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/shutdown.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7

Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7

Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp

Using JRE_HOME:        /usr

Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

Jun 02, 2014 9:37:59 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile

WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]

Jun 02, 2014 9:37:59 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile

WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]

Jun 02, 2014 9:38:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile

WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]

Jun 02, 2014 9:38:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile

WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]

Jun 02, 2014 9:38:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile

WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]

Jun 02, 2014 9:38:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile

WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]

Jun 02, 2014 9:38:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer

SEVERE: Catalina.stop: 

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat7/conf/server.xml (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:468)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:371)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:458)
```

Please suggest me a solution for this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Generally any service in Ubuntu can be managed by

```
sudo service <service_name> <argument>
```

Here service_name stands for name of the service, in your case it is `tomcat7`.

Argument stands for type of the action like `start`,`stop`,`restart`,`status`, in your case it is `stop`.

so finally you can stop tomcat7 with this below command.

```
sudo service tomcat7 stop
```

Comment: Stop is a one time deal.
He would need to use `sudo update-rc.d tomcat7 disable`
to stop it from restarting with pc when it boots

Answer (score 1):

I've tried almost everything I found for this but I finally concluded this to be the best, simple and precise solution:

```
sudo systemctl start tomcat
```

This one is for starting the service

If you want to check the status then

```
sudo systemctl status tomcat
```

And for stopping:

```
sudo systemctl stop tomcat
```

Comment: How does this improve upon the accepted answer?

Comment: Just another direct terminal commands, and it also prevents Tomcat from restarting after reboot.